# Ask sed to ignore all special characters

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I use the following code to delete a line :

```
sed -i "0,/$DELETE_THIS/{/$DELETE_THIS/d;}" file.txt
```

But this code fails if the variable `DELETE_THIS` contains special characters, like `.`, `/`, `*` and so on...

Is there a way to tell `sed` to ignore all special characters and use them as basic text ?

Comment: You would have to escape any special characters in your query expression. Related: [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You have a string in `$DELETE_THIS`, which you want to pass to `sed` in such a way that `sed` will treat it literally.
- For this, you must quote all characters which are meaningful to `sed`.
- Put a backslash before them. For example, using Bash syntax:

  ```
  DELETE_THIS="$(<<< "$DELETE_THIS" sed -e 's`[][\\/.*^$]`\\&`g')"
  ```
- This will convert, for example, `^ab[c-d]\ef$` into `\^ab\[c-d\]\\ef\$`.