# How to find and replace string in my .txt files?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have files in which I am storing some credentials, I want shell script to read that file and check if current cred matches searched string, replace that at that location only.

I tried below code but it always append and does not even replace string.

```
cat $FILESOURCE | sed -e "s/$TEXTTOSEARCH/$TEXTTOREPLACE/g" >> $FILESOURCE
```

where

- `FILESOURCE` = my .txt file to read
- `TEXTTOSEARCH` = string to search
- `TEXTTOREPLACE` = text to replace

Note: I don't want to mess up existing file, instead it just open file for reading check if searched string found, then replace it, if not found dont do anything to file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make iconv replace the input file with the converted output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10241/how-can-i-make-iconv-replace-the-input-file-with-the-converted-output)

Comment: sed will do a find and replace, that is find, **then** replace, if nothing is found, no replacement will occur.

Comment: Are you sure your credentials (in particular `$TEXTTOSEARCH`) cannot contain the `/` or any characters that have a special meaning in the context of regular expressions?

Comment: Yes it contains special characters  including /  \  * ( ) _ - {  } . @ ~

Answer (score 3):

Of course it appends, since you are using `>>`, which means append.

What do you have in `$TEXTTOSEARCH`? Are there letters only or any special characters? If you have special characters that have special meaning in regular expression, you have to escape them in order to work correctly. For instance `.` means any character. You should replace it with `\.` in your `$TEXTTOSEARCH`. Look [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) for more details.

There are many ways how to handle your files. I would suggest you use

```
sed -i.bak -e "s/$TEXTTOSEARCH/$TEXTTOREPLACE/g" $FILESOURCE
```

In that way sed will replace text in your file and make a backup with `.bak` extension. If you want it another way specify more in detail. Your question is not very clear, as you say you do not want to mess up existing file, and you want to replace text in that file?

Comment: Yes those have any special characters example G]07N!qRsf2@q3I?rxI8
BR4DzujZlTHS@-oA}9eq
lf!_lOf5hN1!:b_v%zHJ
8D9QDG$VZ?@h.J,20p6K
@FG7Vf9YR2{9HWfI5yo{
IKpgAqYC:O@4=r!$aI{m
+;n*T.Plq5lXj3R:&_5L

Comment: But its very complicated to use escape characters it can be any , purpose is to simplify task, we just give source string and file will be replaced with given string at perticular location.

Comment: Doing escaping character stuff is tedious here. Don't we have anything that just as a full string replace with given new string (having special characters in it ? )

Comment: If using sed, you will have to escape characters. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486131/ask-sed-to-ignore-all-special-characters

Comment: is there any other way, let say I don't want to use SED command or escaping things

Comment: There must be. I am not aware of a program that can do that, because they all support regular expressions. You can write a program yourself. It should be easy. Here are examples in Python https://pythonexamples.org/python-replace-string-in-file/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128144/replace-string-within-file-contents

Comment: Here you have an example in Perl that ignores regular expressions https://stackoverflow.com/a/18794142/3887162